# LEFT JOIN but in PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays, left-join

I have two arrays.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12
            [user_id] => 1
            [date] => 2013-10-21 23:01:52
            [type] => 1
            [name] => Wypłata UNDICOM
            [quantity] => 0
            [value] => 1700
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 13
            [user_id] => 1
            [date] => 2013-10-21 23:01:52
            [type] => 0
            [name] => Rata (gwarancja MacBook Air)
            [quantity] => 0
            [value] => 90
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 16
            [user_id] => 1
            [date] => 2013-10-21 23:01:52
            [type] => 0
            [name] => TESCO (zakupy)
            [quantity] => 0
            [value] => 0
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [data_id] => 16
            [name] => Coca-Cola
            [quantity] => 2
            [value] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [data_id] => 16
            [name] => Pizza
            [quantity] => 1
            [value] => 10
        )

)
```

I want to display this two arrays, but first array is a category and second have elements.
The relations are between id (first array) and data_id (second array).
In MySQL is simple LEFT JOIN, but i have no idea if is function like that in PHP.
I just tried code some if's etc. but without success.
I want a simple solution, so if it's impossibile then tell me that.

Cheers!

Comment: Where are you getting the data from? I would try to fix it there, but if you can't, I would loop once through the first array to generate an array where the key is the ID. That would make looking up values extremely easy.

Comment: @Grzegorz Can you tell us what's the end result you're expecting

Comment: I want to do a mathematical operations on this arrays, but as You can see, there is a Group (first array) and optional with element lists (array second). I need to assigned all, like Group -> Elements, or if null elements or dosnt exists, get only Group

Comment: I has changed arrays, so if there is a items for category it create in category array a new array named bills. But how to displays arrays with some filtering? I want to display all arrays with 'type'=>1 ?

Answer (score 1):

Like jeroen mentioned, you can loop through both arrays and get only those elements which have a join.

```
$len1 = count(array1);
$len2 = count(array2);

for($i = 0 ; $i < len1 ; $i++)
{
   for($j = 0 ; $j < len2 ; $j++)
   {
       if($array1[$i]['id'] == $array2[$j]['data_id'])
       {
            //some processing which you want to do with this data
       }
   }
}
```