# php compare 2 associative arrays and combine on the same Key only

Tags: php, arrays

I have a special condition that need to **combine two associative array on the same keys Only**

```
$array_1['key1']="";
$array_1['key2']="";
$array_1['key3']="";
$array_1['key4']="";
$array_1['key5']="";
$array_1['key6']="";
$array_1['key7']="";

$array_2['key1']="value1";
$array_2['key3']="value2";
$array_2['key4']="value3";
$array_2['key8']="value4";

$results=array_merge($array_1,$array_2);

foreach ($results as $key=>$value){
 echo ''.$key.'-<input type="text" value="'.$value.'"><br>';
}
```

**If i use *array_merge*, all the keys will be combined together, just like the right side of the screenshot; that's not what I want. I only want the left side of the screenshot**

**To put it simpler, I want to display $array_1 Keys and join $array_2 into $array_1 with the same Keys only.**

[image] 
Anyone can help?

Comment: mmm, have you take a look to array_merge?

Comment: what if `$array_1` keys contains values? for example `$array_1['key1'] = "value"`  and also `$array_2['key1']` contains value, what is the expected result ?

Comment: @Mohammad depends the order of the arrays when you calla rray megerge, to prioritize one from each other, an get prioritized the last array when is called

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to reach your goal. One of them is to use [`array_intersect_key()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) to keep the values of `$array_2` only for keys it has in common with  `$array_1` and merge only this intersection into `$array_1`.

Something like:

```
$results = array_merge($array_1, array_intersect_key($array_2, $array_1));
```

Comment: Great answer, no need of looping entire array. Should be added also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696820/left-join-but-in-php-array

Comment: @GiacomoPittalis this is not working check this - https://3v4l.org/fQ2MS

Comment: @GiacomoPittalis how is this answer useful to the question you linked to? That is a different question with a different setup.

Comment: @Mohammad key8 is missing in result array

Comment: @Bhaskar exactly that what is the question about, "To put it simpler, I want to display $array_1 Keys and join $array_2 into $array_1 with the same Keys only."

Answer (score 2):

try this  use the keys of $array_1 to show the desired result

```
$array_1['key1']="";
$array_1['key2']="";
$array_1['key3']="";
$array_1['key4']="";
$array_1['key5']="";
$array_1['key6']="";
$array_1['key7']="";

$array_2['key1']="value1";
$array_2['key3']="value2";
$array_2['key4']="value3";
$array_2['key8']="value4";

$results=array_merge($array_1,$array_2);

foreach ($array_1 as $key => $value){
 echo ''.$key.'-<input type="text" value="'.$results[$key].'"><br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

like this

```
$array_1['key1']="";
$array_1['key2']="";
$array_1['key3']="";
$array_1['key4']="";
$array_1['key5']="";
$array_1['key6']="";
$array_1['key7']="";

$array_2['key1']="value1";
$array_2['key3']="value2";
$array_2['key4']="value3";
$array_2['key8']="value4";
foreach ($array_1 as $k => $v) {
    if(isset($array_2[$k])){
        $array_1[$k] = empty($array_1[$k])?$array_2[$k]:$array_1[$k];
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array_1);
```

result is

```
Array
(
    [key1] => value1
    [key2] => 
    [key3] => value2
    [key4] => value3
    [key5] => 
    [key6] => 
    [key7] => 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you have to loop through array_1 then using array_key_exists() function check if this key axis td in areay_2 if yes set the value of $array_1[key]=$array_2[key]

```
$array_1['key1']="";
$array_1['key2']="";
$array_1['key3']="";
$array_1['key4']="";
$array_1['key5']="";
$array_1['key6']="";
$array_1['key7']="";
$array_2['key1']="value1";
$array_2['key3']="value2";
$array_2['key4']="value3";
$array_2['key8']="value4";
foreach ($array_1 as $key=>$value){
if(array_key_exists($key,$array_2)){
$array_1[$key]=$array_2[$key];
} 
print_r($array_1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution

```
$array_1['key1']="";
$array_1['key2']="";
$array_1['key3']="";
$array_1['key4']="";
$array_1['key5']="";
$array_1['key6']="";
$array_1['key7']="";

$array_2['key1']="value1";
$array_2['key3']="value2";
$array_2['key4']="value3";
$array_2['key8']="value4";

$updatedArray = [];
$finalArray = array_intersect_key($array_1,$array_2);
foreach ($finalArray as $key=>$value){
    $updatedArray[$key] = $array_2[$key];
}

print_r($updatedArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that:

```
$keys = array_keys($array2);
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
    if (in_array($key, $keys)) {
        echo ''.$key.'-<input type="text" value="'.$value.'"><br>';
    }
}
```